# Determining Which Collection of Subsets is a Simplex

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am currently working on combinatorics in my discrete mathematics course, and I've come across a problem that I'm having difficulty with. We're using the textbook "Discrete Mathematics - An Open Introduction".

A collection of non-empty subsets of the set {1, 2,...,n} is referred to as a 'simplex' if, for any subset S included in the collection, any non-empty subset T of S is also in the collection.

Given this definition, I need to determine which one of the following collections of subsets of {1, 2,..., n} is a simplex:
(A) All subsets S where 1 belongs to S.

(B) All subsets with precisely 4 elements.

(C) All non-empty subsets which do not have any even numbers.

(D) All non-empty subsets except for the subset {1}.

For option (A), if I consider a set like {1, 2}, then the subset {1} is also in the collection. But I am unsure about sets like {1, 3, 4} and its subsets.

For option (B), if the collection consists of all sets with 4 elements, I'm thinking about subsets with fewer elements and whether they are included.

For (C) and (D), I am unsure how to approach them based on the given definition of a simplex.

Could someone guide me on how to analyze these options based on the definition of a simplex and elaborate more on it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

option(a) can't be true as {2} is not included in the collection of subsets which is subset of the subset {1,2}

option(b) can't be true as 3 elements are not included in the collection of subsets.

option(d) cannot be true as {1} is not included which is subset of the subset {1,2}

hence option(c) is correct